# How to find average of object data type in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

| Memory Speed | Device Weight | Screen Size | GPU Memory Type | GPU Memory Size | GPU Type | Panel Type | Processor Generation | Processor | Operating System | Card Reader | Backlit Keyboard | Max Processor Speed | Max Screen Resolution | Fingerprint Reader | RAM (System Memory) | SSD Capacity | Product Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2666 MHz | 2 - 4 kg | 15.6 inches | Onboard | Shared | Integrated Graphics | LED | 10th Generation | 1005G1 | Windows 11 Home | None | 0 | 3.4 GHz | 1920 x 1080 | None | 4 GB | 256 GB | Notebook | Very Low |

I have a dataset like upside. dataset formatted as xlsx file. I'm doing data preprocessing now. mean, median, mod i have to find.
"Conducting a descriptive data analysis of the dataset involves examining record counts, attribute numbers, attribute types, measures of central tendency, measures of dispersion from the center, and generating five-number summaries"
the certain explanation :)

Now i want to ask how to find mean for object data type according to my dataset?
Backlit Keyboard column's average only i can find now.

```
import pandas as panda

 dataset = panda.read_excel('data.xlsx')
 print(dataset.info())
```

RangeIndex: 994 entries, 0 to 993
Data columns (total 19 columns):

| Column Name | Non-Null Count | Dtype |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Memory Speed | 888 | object |
| Device Weight | 985 | object |
| Screen Size | 994 | object |
| GPU Memory Type | 884 | object |
| GPU Memory Size | 946 | object |
| GPU Type | 955 | object |
| Panel Type | 994 | object |
| Processor Generation | 946 | object |
| Processor | 979 | object |
| Operating System | 994 | object |
| Card Reader | 864 | object |
| Backlight | 994 | int64 |
| Max Processor Speed | 950 | object |
| Max Screen Resolution | 988 | object |
| Fingerprint Reader | 886 | object |
| RAM (System Memory) | 987 | object |
| SSD Capacity | 991 | object |
| Product Model | 994 | object |
| Price | 994 | object |

the result of dataset.head():

| Memory Speed | Device Weight | Screen Size | Graphics Card Memory Type | Graphics Card Memory | Graphics Card Type | Screen Panel Type | Processor Generation | Processor | Operating System | Card Reader | Backlit Keyboard | Max Processor Speed | Max Screen Resolution | Fingerprint Reader | RAM (System Memory) | SSD Capacity | Product Model | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1066 MHz | NaN | 10 inches | NaN | 1 GB | NaN | IPS | 1st Generation | 1000M | Android | NaN | 0 | 1.05 GHz | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1 TB | Notebook | High |
| 1066 MHz | NaN | 10 inches | NaN | 1 GB | NaN | IPS | 1st Generation | 1000M | Android | NaN | 0 | 1.05 GHz | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1 TB | Notebook | High |
| 1066 MHz | NaN | 10 inches | NaN | 1 GB | NaN | IPS | 1st Generation | 1000M | Android | NaN | 0 | 1.05 GHz | NaN | NaN | NaN | 1 TB | Notebook | Medium |
| 3200 MHz | 1 - 2 kg | 15.6 inches | GDDR4 | 2 GB | External GPU | LED | 10th Generation | 1035G1 | Windows 10 Home | Yes | 0 | 3.6 GHz | 1920 x 1080 | No | 8 GB | 512 GB | Notebook | Low |
| 3200 MHz | 1 - 2 kg | 15.6 inches | GDDR5 | 2 GB | External GPU | LED | 10th Generation | 1035G1 | Windows 10 Home | No | 0 | 3.6 GHz | 1920 x 1080 | No | 12 GB | 1 TB | Notebook | Low |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pandas describe function:

```
dataset.describe(include = "all")
```

In terms of a better answer than `describe`, there is the issue with converting (when possible) the values to numerical types. So I had to go through tedious checking:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel("Dataset.xlsx") # import data from op's file
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns) # generate an empty copy with headers

for col in df.columns: # go through columns
    if df[col].dtypes == "object": # check if object, if yes go in, if no assign to df_new
        values = list() # init empty list
        for val in df[col].values: # for every value in the column
            if pd.isna(val): # if it is nan, append it to values
                # print("Nan detected in "+str(val))
                values.append(np.nan) # append
            elif " " in val: # if there are spaces, this hints to the existence of number + unit
                # print("space detected in "+val)
                val_splitted = val.split(" ") # split with space
                if "," in val_splitted[0]: # if there is a comma, since the dec points are sometimes with , and sometimes with .
                    val_splitted[0] = val_splitted[0].replace(",", ".") # replace , with .
                if len(val_splitted) == 2: # if there are only two values in the splitted form
                    # print("one space detected in "+val)
                    try: # try to convert to float
                        if col == "SSD Capacity": # only here, since the unit switches between GB and TB
                            if val_splitted[1] == "GB": # 
                                values.append(float(val_splitted[0])/1000) # append divided by 1000
                            else: # else
                                values.append(float(val_splitted[0])) # assign as is
                        else: # if it is not the column SSD Capacity
                            values.append(float(val_splitted[0])) # append the val as is
                    except ValueError: # oops! value cannot be converted, then it is not numeric
                        values.append(val) # assign as is
                else:
                    #print("too many spaces inm keeping "+val+" as it is") 
                    values.append(val) # if too many spaces, such as "1920 x 1080" append as is
            else:
                # print("keeping "+val+" as it is")
                values.append(val) # if no spaces and not nan, assign as is
        df_new[col] = values # assign the values to the column in df_new
    else:
        df_new[col] = df[col] # if the value is not an object type, assign the whole column to df_new
        
print(df_new.describe(include = "all")) # print description
```

The results are like this:

|  | Memory Speed | Screen Size | Backlit | Max Processor Speed | RAM (System Memory) | SSD Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **count** | 888.000 | 994.000 | 994.000 | 950.000 | 987.000 | 991.000 |
| **mean** | 3339.874 | 15.336 | 0.243 | 4.293 | 17.431 | 0.638 |
| **std** | 626.284 | 0.923 | 0.429 | 0.616 | 12.235 | 0.423 |
| **min** | 1066.000 | 10.000 | 0.000 | 1.050 | 4.000 | 0.000 |
| **25%** | 3200.000 | 15.600 | 0.000 | 4.200 | 8.000 | 0.500 |
| **50%** | 3200.000 | 15.600 | 0.000 | 4.400 | 16.000 | 0.512 |
| **75%** | 3200.000 | 15.600 | 0.000 | 4.700 | 16.000 | 1.000 |
| **max** | 6400.000 | 18.400 | 1.000 | 5.600 | 128.000 | 4.000 |

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. `.describe` would exclude the `object` dtype columns from the mean (and other quantile) functions.

Comment: even with `include = "all"` ?

Comment: I tried it right now, for object type the function returns count, # of unique, most recurring and freq, nan everywhere else. For numeric, it returns mean, std, min, quantiles and max

So I guess OP needs to be more precise with how the data looks like

Comment: The OP asks to find "the average of **object** datatype", so your answer is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: I mean... goodluck finding the numerical average of `Operating System`. Maybe with luck, Windows 9 will be found ;)

Comment: Certainly, but your answer doesn't even work with `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}, dtype='object')`. Hence the *irrelevant* in my comment.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the hint

Comment: i have 994 lines and much more missing data i have actually i thought i change the data type but it will take a long time. I cant share all dataset here,can i?

Comment: dataset['Ram (System Memory)'] = dataset['Ram (System Memory)'].apply(lambda x : x.replace("GB","")).astype('float') like this

Comment: @BerreSenaKIRAÇ no you can't, you can however give a sample of your data, as such: 
`df.head()`. 
Actually, it is possible to upload data to some link and then share the link, google drive, so on...

Comment: So your problem is quite specific. You would need to go through the columns and check for the units as well (you have a mix of TB and GB). Separate the value from the unit and then turn the object column into a numerical one. I will edit the answer a bit to make it more relevant...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W-zmE1j7RVI7tpqO1pmWA_5An5N8d8ATqa5nhajdafo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @BerreSenaKIRAÇ did I answer your question? Or would you need something more?

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. i made some differences and i used this function on my project. and i  understand the logic of use. appriciate and regards @TinoD

Comment: Good to hear! can you please close the question by accepting my answer? would appreciate it! Thanks in advance!